# CustomAdapter не работает | Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment, recyclerview

Написал кастомный адаптер:

```
private var list = mutableListOf<Book>()

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.card, parent, false);
    log(list.size.toString())
    return ViewHolder(view);
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int = list.size

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(list[position])
}

fun set(l: MutableList<Book>) {
    this.list.clear()
    this.list.addAll(l);
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

В фрагменте вызываю:

```
val ad = listOf<Book>(
        Book("1","11","12"),
        Book("2", "21","22")
    ) as MutableList<Book>

    recyclerRecommended.apply {
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        adapter = DataAdapter(ad)
    }
```

Но в логкат не выходит сообщения о запуске функции. Что может быть не так?

```
fun log(message:String){
    Log.i("PARSER", message)
}
```

Comment: ПОхоже, что вы не тот список данных используете. У вас, похоже, их в адаптере 2 - один в конструкторе (не используется) и один как поле адаптера - в него вы ничего не добавляете. В итоге ничего и не работает.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, возможно, но как это решить. Kotlin я плохо знаю и не понимаю, как правильно передавать кастомный ArrayList.

Comment: Выберите что-то одно. Например удалите `private var list = mutableListOf<Book>()` и используйте вместо неё в коде имя переменной из конструктора адаптера.

Comment: В адаптере даже описана функция   fun set(l: MutableList<Book>)  для применения списка. Ее наверное и правильней использовать.  После применения адаптера вызвать adapter.set(ad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну я могу ошибаться т.к. не вижу конструктора вашего `Adapter-a`, но вот тут

```
private var list = mutableListOf<Book>()
```

вы создали пустой список. И ничем его не заполнили, а значит у вас не будет элементов в адаптере.

У вас есть метод `set()` он написан правильно, так вот добавляйте элементы с помощью этого метода, а не в конструктор.

Если же вы решили все же добавлять элементы через конструктор, то вы должны убрать ваш `private var list = mutableListOf<Book>()` и использовать тот лист, что есть в аргументах конструктора

```
class Adapter (private val list : List<Book>)
```

либо же сетить ваш `private var list = mutableListOf<Book>()` в блоке `init {}`